# Send circle in direction of mouse in Java

Tags: java, object, jframe

I was working on a game where the ball shoots when I click the mouse one. I'm not too experienced in Java so was confused. It would be like, the ball starts at the bottom middle of the screen (so ballx and bally had their positions) and once the mouse clicks in a direction, the ball would shoot in that direction... 
Thank you

```
package graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ballz extends LASSPanel
{
//Variables for the circle (Global Variables)

int circleX, circleY, circleDX, circleDY, circleSize, circleSpeed;

//Colors
Color circleColor;
Color backgroundColor;
Dimension size;
double mouseX;
double mouseY;

public Ballz()
{
    //Ball Variables
    circleX = 250;
    circleY = 250;
    circleSize = 15;
    circleSpeed = (1);  

    circleColor = new Color (245,245,245);
    backgroundColor = new Color (28,28,28);
    size = new Dimension(0,0);
}
public void update()
{
    //Get size of screen
    getSize(size);

    //Get mouse coordinates
    mouseX = getMouseX();
    mouseY = getMouseY();

    //Call custom method to find angle

    //Screen borders
    if (circleX >= (size.width) - circleSize)
    {
        circleDX = -circleDX;
        circleX = size.width-circleSize;

    }
    if (circleX <= 0)
    {
        circleDX = -circleDX;
        circleX = 0;
    }
    if (circleY >= (size.height -circleSize))
    {
        circleDY = -circleDY;
        circleY = size.height-circleSize;   
    }
    if (circleY <= 0)
    {
        circleDY = -circleDY;
        circleY = 0;
    }

    circleX += circleDX;
    circleY += circleDY;

    repaint();

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{


    //Game Colors
    g.setColor(circleColor);
    g.fillOval(circleX, circleY, circleSize, circleSize);
    setBackground(backgroundColor); 

}
//This is the code that will get the direction between two points that I give.
    public double getAngle (int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{

    double Direction = 0;

    double dx = y2-y1;
    double dy = x2-x1;

     Direction = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

    return Direction;

}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code and we will try find error if something doesnt work

Comment: I haven't been able to add it to my code. The ways that I thought were wrong (like just getting the mouseX and mouseY and making the xDirection and yDirection into the points of mouseX and mouseY

Comment: I added a code that I used to find the direction but thats it.